# With a JavaScript method like alert(), what do you refer to the content within the () as?

Tags: javascript

For example, let's say I was trying to explain to someone what happened when they wrote the following:

`alert("Hello there!");`

I'd tell them the alert method was called when they typed "alert", but how would I refer to the content within the ()?

Comment: Do you mean message parameter?

Answer (score 2):

The data put between the `()` is data being passed to a function, which is known as an [*argument*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)):

> the argument in computer science is thus the actual input expression passed/supplied to a function

A *parameter* is a variable made available in the function definition that holds a passed argument.